# Defining Independent FlagSets in GoLang

Tags: go, command-line, command-line-arguments, go-flag, flag-go

The Go documentation (http://golang.org/pkg/flag/) says:

> The FlagSet type allows one to define independent sets of flags, such as to implement subcommands in a command-line interface.

I need this functionality but I can't figure out how to persuade the flag pkg to do it. When I define two FlagSets, parsing one of them will give me errors and warnings if the commandline has flags that are meant for the second one. Example:

```
f1 := flag.NewFlagSet("f1", flag.ContinueOnError)
apply := f1.Bool("apply", false, "")
silent := f1.Bool("silent", false, "")
if err := f1.Parse(os.Args[1:]); err == nil {
    fmt.Println(*apply, *silent)
}
f2 := flag.NewFlagSet("f2", flag.ContinueOnError)
reset := f2.Bool("reset", false, "")
if err := f2.Parse(os.Args[1:]); err == nil {
    fmt.Println(*reset)
}
```

I get all sorts of warnings if I try to do `cmd -apply` OR `cmd -reset`. I want to keep these FlagSets separate because I want to only have `-silent` work for `-apply`.

What am I missing?

Comment: without getting into this specific problem - allow me to highly recommend an excellent alternative flags parser that I am using (not my work, I just like it).  https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags

Comment: Parsing a `FlagSet` will consume all options and won't ignore some, so you'll have to determine before parsing a FlagSet which one applies. If "reset" and "apply" are subcommand with different flags determine which subcommand to run and parse that FlagSet. What you are trying to do cannot be done.

Comment: For my own future reference, parsing multiple subcommands can be done with https://github.com/google/subcommands.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are meant to distinguish between subcommands first, and then call `Parse` on the right `FlagSet`.

```
f1 := flag.NewFlagSet("f1", flag.ContinueOnError)
silent := f1.Bool("silent", false, "")
f2 := flag.NewFlagSet("f2", flag.ContinueOnError)
loud := f2.Bool("loud", false, "")

switch os.Args[1] {
  case "apply":
    if err := f1.Parse(os.Args[2:]); err == nil {
      fmt.Println("apply", *silent)
    }
  case "reset":
    if err := f2.Parse(os.Args[2:]); err == nil {
      fmt.Println("reset", *loud)
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/eaEEx_EReX

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is possible to consume one set of flags while capturing the flags not recognized by the first set and while discarding the error messages that the flag package is prepared to emit whenever it runs into an option it doesn't recognize.

Here's one way to do it.

```golang
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func gentleParse(flagset *flag.FlagSet, args []string) []string {
    if len(args) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    r := make([]string, 0, len(args))

    flagset.Init(flagset.Name(), flag.ContinueOnError)
    w := flagset.Output()
    flagset.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
    defer flagset.SetOutput(w)

    next := args

    for len(next) > 0 {
        if next[0] == "--" {
            r = append(r, next...)
            break
        }
        if !strings.HasPrefix(next[0], "-") {
            r, next = append(r, next[0]), next[1:]
            continue
        }
        if err := flagset.Parse(next); err != nil {
            const prefix = "flag provided but not defined: "
            if strings.HasPrefix(err.Error(), prefix) {
                pull := strings.TrimPrefix(err.Error(), prefix)
                for next[0] != pull {
                    next = next[1:]
                }
                r, next = append(r, next[0]), next[1:]
                continue
            }
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", err)
            flagset.SetOutput(w)
            flag.Usage()
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        next = flag.Args()
    }
    return r
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just change these code

```
if err := f2.Parse(os.Args[1:]); err == nil {
    fmt.Println(*reset)
}
```

to

```
f2.Parse(os.Args[1:])
fmt.Println(*reset)
```

but the warning is just left on the console.if u wanna remove it ,modify /usr/local/go/src/flag/flag.go and recompile the golang ..
or do a copy of flag package.

→_→ 怀疑的眼神~~